# Last bootstrap column brings underneath row up on jquery animate

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am building my first backbone app with bootstrap. It is a simple Contact Manager which so far only reads the contacts from an array and displays the contact's information. Initially the contact card is minimized but upon clicking inside the contact card it expands using jquery animate. However, the last column messes up the layout as it brings the row underneath it up and i have no idea why. I have uploaded my app on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanmanolov90/v0g3vnaL/1/). Can you please help me as to why the last column is messing up during animation bringing up the rows underneath?

my underscore backbone template

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <label class="navbar-brand">Backbone Contact Manager</label>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="filter" class="form-group col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <label for="filterSelect">Filter Groups:</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="directory" class="row"></div>


    <!-- UNDERSCORE TEMPLATES -->
    <script type="text/template" id="contactTemplate">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <a class="btn contact buffer">
                <div class="contact-header"></div>
                <div class="img-div">
                    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/A/Y/O/m/o/N/placeholder.svg" class="contact-image img-circle">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-name">
                    <h4> <%= name %></h4>
                </div>
                <div class='contact-info'> 
                    <br>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span>
                    <label><%= group %></label>
                    <br>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
                    <label><%= address %></label>
                    <br>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                    <label><%= email %></label>
                    <br>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>
                    <label><%= phone %></label>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

my backbone view with the animation

```
var ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //get the undercore template
    template: _.template($('#contactTemplate').html()),

    events: {
        'click a': 'renderContactInfo',
    },

    //always render on initialize so you don't have to later
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    renderContactInfo: function() {
        var currentContact= this.$el.find('a');
        if (currentContact.hasClass('addHeight')) {
            currentContact.removeClass('addHeight');
            this.$el.find("div:nth-child(4)").toggle();
            currentContact.animate({ height: '90px', 'margin-bottom':'120px' });

        } 
        else {
            currentContact.animate({ height: '200px', 'margin-bottom': '0px'});
            currentContact.addClass('addHeight');
            this.$el.find("div:nth-child(4)").toggle();

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think its caused by the contact columns sitting outside of a `.row` container

Comment: you mean the underscore template? that is rendered inside the directory div which has class .row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over it your problem seems to be caused here:

```
currentContact.removeClass('addHeight');
            this.$el.find("div:nth-child(4)").toggle();
            currentContact.animate({ height: '90px', 'margin-bottom':'120px' });

        } 
        else {
            currentContact.animate({ height: '200px', 'margin-bottom': '0px'});
            currentContact.addClass('addHeight');
            this.$el.find("div:nth-child(4)").toggle();
```

The first has a height and margin bottom totaling 210px while the second only has a total of 200px, so change the value of the margin-bottom in the else to 10px

```
currentContact.animate({ height: '200px', 'margin-bottom': '10px'});
```

This only half solves your problem, the next col gets pushed down but then pops back up. What seems to be happening is that some class maybe `.buffer` is pushing the content down then once it is overwritten and the margin-bottom is changed from 120px to 10px it slots back into place.

You might need to look into the order that classes are added or have a class removed first then add the other class to change its margins. Hope this gives you an idea of where to look.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. i finally just got it to work